# instead of declaring activity in manifest error is thrown

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, manifest

i have  two activity show and view. i have declared view activity in the manifest.xml but then also its throwing error and getting closed unexpectedly

manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.Create" > </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.Details" > </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.Setting" > </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.Show" > </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abhishekp.passmanage.View"> </activity>


   </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: show.xml]

on clicking any button i am passing the profile name as

```
    public class Show extends Activity {

Button showhome,atm,bank,mail,mobile,other,personal,social;
String profile;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);

//buttons id declarations

    showhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            profile = "SHOW";
            main.putExtra("key", profile);
            startActivityForResult(main, 0);
        }

    });

    atm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent d1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), View.class);
            profile = "ATM";
            d1.putExtra("key", profile);
            startActivityForResult(d1, 0);
        }
    });

    bank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            profile="BANK";
            Intent d2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), View.class);
            d2.putExtra("key", profile);
            startActivityForResult(d2, 0);
        }
    });

    mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            profile="MAIL";
            Intent d3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), View.class);
            d3.putExtra("key", profile);
            startActivityForResult(d3, 0);
        }
    });
```

in view activity i have only 1 textview
and in view activity i am trying to get the value  as

```
package com.abhishekp.passmanage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class View extends Activity {

TextView profilename;
String profile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);


    profilename = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profilename);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        profile = extras.getString("key");
        profilename.setText("Profile : " +profile);
    }

}

}
```

but its throwing an error in log cat as

```
LOGCAT

09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:      Unable to find explicit activity class {com.abhishekp.passmanage/android.view.View}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.abhishekp.passmanage.Show$2.onClick(Show.java:50)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-22 16:18:27.267: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 16:18:33.766: I/Process(558): Sending signal. PID: 558 SIG: 9
```

Comment: rename your View activity class and try to avoid confusion

Comment: Do you have right import of View class? May be you have imported android View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `View` class already available in android so  change class name or use `setClass` and `setComponent` to start Activity as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.abhishekp.passmanage", 
                                          "com.abhishekp.passmanage.View");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abhishekp.passmanage",
                                          "com.abhishekp.passmanage.View"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you were right i changed the name of the class and changed it in manifest it worked..

Comment: @Abhishek : you can also startActivity activity without changing name in manifast file by providing much information to system using setClassName and setComponent.